# How to find specific dynamic control and get value

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making student attendance system. I am creating dynamic control and assigning values from database. Now I want to know how to find desired dynamic control and how I will get value from it.

I don't know how I can find desired control using a `foreach` loop.

This is my code for creating dynamic controls.

```
public void genControl(StudentAttendence sta)
{
    StudentAttendenceBSLDAL stabd = new StudentAttendenceBSLDAL();
    List<string[]> liName = stabd.takStudent(sta);
    counts = Convert.ToInt16(stabd.takStudent(sta).Count);
    for (int i=0; i< stabd.takStudent(sta).Count;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<liName[i].Count();j++)
        {
            Label lblStudentname = new Label();
            Label lblStId = new Label();
            lblStId.Name = "lblStId"+i.ToString()+j.ToString();
            lblStudentname.Name = "liName"+i.ToString()+j.ToString();
            lblStId.AutoSize = true;
            lblStudentname.AutoSize = true;
            if (j==0)
            {
                lblStId.Text = liName[i][j].ToString(); 

            }
            if(j==1)
            {
                lblStudentname.Text = liName[i][j].ToString();

            }
            lblStId.AutoSize = true;

            lblStudentname.AutoSize = true;
            if (i == 1)
            {
                lblStId.Location = new Point(41, 229);
                lblStudentname.Location = new Point(153, 7);
            }
            else
            {
                lblStId.Location = new Point(3, 7 + 20);
                lblStudentname.Location = new Point(153, 7 + 20);
            }

            this.Controls.Add(lblStId);
            panel1.Controls.Add(lblStudentname);
        }
        CheckBox cba = new CheckBox();
        cba.Name = "cba" + i.ToString() ;
        cba.Text = "A";
        cba.AutoSize = true;

        CheckBox cbp = new CheckBox();
        cbp.Name = i.ToString()  ;
        cbp.Text = "P";
        cbp.AutoSize = true;

        CheckBox cbl = new CheckBox();
        cbl.Name = "cbl" + i.ToString() ;
        cbl.Text = "L";
        cbl.AutoSize = true;
        if (i == 1)
        {
            cbp.Location = new Point(590, 3);
            cba.Location = new Point(631, 3);
            cbl.Location = new Point(670, 3);
        }
        else
        {
            cbp.Location = new Point(590, 3 + 23);
            cba.Location = new Point(631, 3 + 23);
            cbl.Location = new Point(670, 3 + 23);
        }
        panel1.Controls.Add(cbp);
        panel1.Controls.Add(cba);
        panel1.Controls.Add(cbl);
    }
}
```

This is button control event in which I am trying to find control and get it value.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StudentAttendence sta = new StudentAttendence();
    StudentAttendenceBSLDAL stabd = new StudentAttendenceBSLDAL();
  //  List<string[]> liName = stabd.takStudent(sta);
    for (int i=0;i<counts;i++)
    {
         CheckBox cbP = panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name.Equals("cbp"+i.ToString()));

     //   Label stid = panel1.Controls.Find("lblStId" + i.ToString(), false).First() as Label;
        if(!cbP.IsChecked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("control found");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you save the dynamically created controls in an own data structure, so you can use this to work with them if needed

Comment: Florian Koch  I can't understand this " save the dynamically created controls in an own data structure ".

Comment: You just forgot to set the name corrctly:  `cbp.Name = i.ToString()  ;` should be `cbp.Name = "cbp" + i.ToString();`

Comment: you could, for example, create a dictionary that has a student name as key and the corresponding control as value

Comment: Ofir Winegarten I give this name cbp.Name = "cbp" + i.ToString(); I want to distinguish between other dynamic checkboxes.

Comment: @SyedUsama Maybe that's what you wanted to do, and you do it for `cba` and `cbl`, but you don't do it for `cbp`

Answer (score 0):

You can save your control list into a SortedList.
You can use this sorted list for further processing